# Fetch ids(Primary Key) from table where ids not available in table within range

Tags: mysql, query, phpmyadmin

I have `table` named `Student`. It have primary key `student_id` which is `auto increment` and `not null`.

Now `Student` contains around 5000 records.

After passed out from university, we need to delete specific student record from `Student` and related child table as well.

It is working good.

I need to get those numbers who are not in `student_id` range.

For ex.

I have 5000 records. So assume range is 1-5000. In `Student` table, there may be data with primary key :

`student_id` :

1
2
4
5
6
7
9
12
15
etc...

So I want deleted ids, like : 3, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, etc... And need this result in some text file.

Finally I have 2 questions :

- Need query to get those deleted ids
- Can I export result in some file after fired query ?

Comment: If you want the numbers to delete from a child table its even easier, you delete the child where there isn't a student_id match. Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384127/delete-sql-rows-where-ids-do-not-have-a-match-from-another-table#3384143)

Comment: 1) Generate pseudotable with the numbers in a assumed range (or from 1 up to MAX(ID), if 8+ - in CTE). LEFT JOIN your Student table to it by ID and select numbers which not exists in a table. 2) Use `SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE`.

Comment: @danblack That I know...But I need from master table only.

Comment: @Akina Can you help me to write exact query ?

Comment: Specify your MySQL version.

Comment: @Akina - `Server version: 5.6.40 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)`
- `Protocol version: 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT n
FROM (
        SELECT 1000*n1+100*n2+10*n3+n4+1 n
        FROM 
                (
                SELECT 0 n1 UNION 
                SELECT 1 UNION 
                SELECT 2 UNION 
                SELECT 3 UNION 
                SELECT 4 UNION 
                SELECT 5 UNION 
                SELECT 6 UNION 
                SELECT 7 UNION 
                SELECT 8 UNION 
                SELECT 9 
                ) n1,
                (
                SELECT 0 n2 UNION 
                SELECT 1 UNION 
                SELECT 2 UNION 
                SELECT 3 UNION 
                SELECT 4 UNION 
                SELECT 5 UNION 
                SELECT 6 UNION 
                SELECT 7 UNION 
                SELECT 8 UNION 
                SELECT 9
                ) n2,
                (
                SELECT 0 n3 UNION 
                SELECT 1 UNION 
                SELECT 2 UNION 
                SELECT 3 UNION 
                SELECT 4 UNION 
                SELECT 5 UNION 
                SELECT 6 UNION 
                SELECT 7 UNION 
                SELECT 8 UNION 
                SELECT 9
                ) n3,
                (
                SELECT 0 n4 UNION 
                SELECT 1 UNION 
                SELECT 2 UNION 
                SELECT 3 UNION 
                SELECT 4 UNION 
                SELECT 5 UNION 
                SELECT 6 UNION 
                SELECT 7 UNION 
                SELECT 8 UNION 
                SELECT 9
                ) n4
        HAVING n < (
                    SELECT MAX(student_id)
                    FROM Student
                   )
     ) numbers
LEFT JOIN Student ON student_id = n
WHERE student_id IS NULL
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2f08e9afeb85ceee273eb8311e9b44fd)

Comment: It is throwing error. Here it is : `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION 
                SELECT 2 UNION 
                SELECT 3 UNION 
      ' at line 7`

Comment: Query text edited, fiddle added.

Comment: It is working... I got deleted ids. Thanks...!!!